# Why does the manual warn you not to sleep in your car?

Tags: safety

'Warning

Do not sleep in a vehicle with air conditioning or heating system on. It may cause serious harm or death due to a drop in the oxygen level and/or body temperature.'

https://www.kia.com/content/dam/kwcms/kme/fi/fi/assets/contents/service/service-care/help-books/english/Kia-e-Niro-English-owners-manual.pdf

I don't understand, can anyone explain? This is included in the manual for the Kia eNiro, which is an electric car.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica No, because my car is electric and doesn't produce carbon monoxide.

Comment: The previous question says -0- about CO or exhaust within the cabin.

Comment: It doesn't mention carbon monoxide, but lack of oxygen, which is consumed by breathing. Modern cars produce such litle carbon monoxide you can't even do *felo de se* in one.

Comment: It's likely a "CYA" warning from the lawyers at Kia.